# CSS Links with Node Proxy

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, proxy

In my project I have a React client (made with create-react-app), and Node.js server with express. The client runs on `localhost:3000`, and the server on `localhost:5000`.

In my client `package.json` I have the following: `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` which allows me to access API routes from the node side (for example, `/users/dothis` rather than `localhost:5000/users/dothis`).

In my server `package.json` I have the following scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "test": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

Now, in React there is an App.css file where I put in my custom CSS. However when I do something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'nucleo-icons';
  src: url("/fonts/nucleo-icons.eot");
  src: url("/fonts/nucleo-icons.eot") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/fonts/nucleo-icons.woff2") format("woff2"), url("/fonts/nucleo-icons.woff") format("woff"), url("/fonts/nucleo-icons.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/fonts/nucleo-icons.svg") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I get the following error:

`Proxy error: Could not proxy request /fonts/nucleo-icons.woff2 from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000.`

It seems that the CSS file is taking the url and trying to pass it through the proxy over to localhost:5000 - but I obviously don't want that as I just want to set the css location path for the icons.

Does anyone know how to get around this? Changing the path to begin with `./` instead of `/` doesn't seem to work. And it seems like any src path I set will likely also hit the same roadblock..